# What is gained by appointing a special counsel to oversee the Trump investigations?

Tags: united-states, law, donald-trump, special-prosecutor

A [special counsel was named](https://www.npr.org/2022/11/18/1137736663/special-counsel-trump-justice-department-jan-6-mar-a-lago) by the DOJ to take care of the Trump legal investigations.

The goal of this is to help remove the investigation from politics. By naming a special counsel, the investigation is not being done by Biden or his appointed attorney general. However, I do not see how this helps. The special counsel was still appointed by the attorney general. It is no more removed from politics than if it was done by the DOJ.

What is gained by appointing the special counsel?

Comment: The special counsel is a registered independent and was specifically chosen for his lack of political connections -- and for his skills. Not that that helped. Trump immediately decried the appointment as a witch hunt.

Comment: @DavidHammen Considering he has said the same thing about members of his own party I don't think that this would be considered unexpected.

Comment: A political smoking gun. I think the DOJ has collected enough information to charge Trump but needs a cover to ride suspicious of favoring the party that appointed him.